# Determine firmware MCU from binary image

Tags: firmware

Tough problem - trying to reverse engineer a CANBUS controller for which I can download firmware (as far as I can tell, binary image, not ELF) but I dont know what MCU it uses.  `binwalk`, `r2` dont give me anything useful.   Binwalk opcodes match mipsel but function signatures is garbage.

What can I do to determine MCU from firmware?

Comment: are you able to share the file via dropbox or equivalent?

Comment: @julian https://www.dataspeedinc.com/release-packages/  Dataspeed knows how to control Ford steering via Active Park messages.  Inside archives are Steer firmware for several Ford platforms and thats where I am hoping to understand protocol

Comment: For example DBW_Kit_FORD_20200221/Firmware/FORD_P5/FORD_P5_STEER_RevA_v1.2.0.hex is Ford F-150 firmware for Dataspeed HW module.  I converted hex to binary, relevant strings appear in hexdump, but thats as far as I managed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear to be MIPS 32-bit little-endian machine code.

---

First, the file was converted from .hex to binary via

```
$ objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary FORD_P5_STEER_RevA_v1.2.0.hex FORD_P5_STEER_RevA_v1.2.0.bin
```

After looking at a `binwalk` entropy plot and a hex dump, I sliced out the first `0x00021330` bytes, because nearly everything after is just 0x00 bytes.

```
000212f0  5f 50 35 20 53 74 65 65  72 00 00 00 20 24 00 00  |_P5 Steer... $..|
00021300  00 04 08 10 14 18 00 00  08 00 e0 03 00 60 62 41  |.............`bA|
00021310  08 00 e0 03 20 60 62 41  08 00 e0 03 00 00 00 00  |.... `bA........|
00021320  08 00 e0 03 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00021330  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................| <--\
*                                                                                 |-- Huge gap
00071e40  01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 46 4f 52 44  |............FORD| <--/
00071e50  20 50 35 20 53 74 65 65  72 69 6e 67 20 45 6d 75  | P5 Steering Emu|
00071e60  6c 61 74 6f 72 20 28 46  4f 52 44 5f 50 35 5f 53  |lator (FORD_P5_S|
00071e70  54 45 45 52 29 20 52 65  76 41 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TEER) RevA......|
00071e80  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
02bf9e80  00 9d 1f 3c 70 79 ff 37  08 00 e0 03 00 00 00 00  |...<py.7........|
02bf9e90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
02bfce70  ff ff ff 3e d9 79 f9 ff  5b 0e 66 ff ff ff ff 7f  |...>.y..[.f.....|
02bfce80
```

[ISAdetect](https://isadetect.com/) results:

```
{
  "prediction": {
    "wordsize": 32,
    "endianness": "little",
    "architecture": "mips"
  },
  "prediction_probability": 0.81
}
```

To confirm, I extracted the machine code from the slice and compared it to a reference:
[image: ford code vs. reference]

The byte value distributions closely match.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to proceed from there, this is very helpful.  I did not know about ISADetect

Comment: @Anycorn you are welcome. I think most people do not know about ISAdetect, sadly. It is relatively new, released in 2019. I only know about it because it is related to my own research

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed valid MIPS litte-endian code:

```
seg000:1D0121F0 A8 FF BD 27                 addiu   $sp, -0x58
seg000:1D0121F4 04 00 A1 AF                 sw      $at, 0x58+var_54($sp)
seg000:1D0121F8 08 00 A2 AF                 sw      $v0, 0x58+var_50($sp)
seg000:1D0121FC 0C 00 A3 AF                 sw      $v1, 0x58+var_4C($sp)
seg000:1D012200 10 00 A4 AF                 sw      $a0, 0x58+var_48($sp)
seg000:1D012204 14 00 A5 AF                 sw      $a1, 0x58+var_44($sp)
seg000:1D012208 18 00 A6 AF                 sw      $a2, 0x58+var_40($sp)
seg000:1D01220C 1C 00 A7 AF                 sw      $a3, 0x58+var_3C($sp)
seg000:1D012210 20 00 A8 AF                 sw      $t0, 0x58+var_38($sp)
seg000:1D012214 24 00 A9 AF                 sw      $t1, 0x58+var_34($sp)
seg000:1D012218 28 00 AA AF                 sw      $t2, 0x58+var_30($sp)
seg000:1D01221C 2C 00 AB AF                 sw      $t3, 0x58+var_2C($sp)
seg000:1D012220 30 00 AC AF                 sw      $t4, 0x58+var_28($sp)
seg000:1D012224 34 00 AD AF                 sw      $t5, 0x58+var_24($sp)
seg000:1D012228 38 00 AE AF                 sw      $t6, 0x58+var_20($sp)
seg000:1D01222C 3C 00 AF AF                 sw      $t7, 0x58+var_1C($sp)
seg000:1D012230 40 00 B8 AF                 sw      $t8, 0x58+var_18($sp)
seg000:1D012234 44 00 B9 AF                 sw      $t9, 0x58+var_14($sp)
seg000:1D012238 48 00 BF AF                 sw      $ra, 0x58+var_10($sp)
seg000:1D01223C 12 40 00 00                 mflo    $t0
seg000:1D012240 4C 00 A8 AF                 sw      $t0, 0x58+var_C($sp)
seg000:1D012244 10 40 00 00                 mfhi    $t0
seg000:1D012248 50 00 A8 AF                 sw      $t0, 0x58+var_8($sp)
seg000:1D01224C 01 9D 1A 3C+                li      $k0, 0x9D012CA4
seg000:1D01224C A4 2C 5A 27
seg000:1D012254 00 00 00 00                 nop
seg000:1D012258 00 68 04 40                 mfc0    $a0, Cause       # Cause of last exception
seg000:1D01225C 00 60 05 40                 mfc0    $a1, SR          # Status register
seg000:1D012260 09 F8 40 03                 jalr    $k0
seg000:1D012264 00 00 00 00                 nop
```

I suspect the device is using something from the Microchip's [PIC32 series](http://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikrobasic/pic32/help/memory_organization.htm).

Comment: Igor, thanks.  The disassembler you used was IDA?

Comment: Yes, it’s from IDA